# Calculation of Magnetic Field Lines

Tags: magnetic-fields, dipole

I am doing some research on how to calculate magnetic field lines for a bar magnet.

So far I have found the following equations:
\begin{align}
\frac{B_r}{B_\theta} &= \frac{d_r}{rd_\theta}\\
B_r& = \frac{-2M\sin\theta}{r^3}\\
B_\theta &= \frac{M\cos\theta}{r^3}
\end{align}

But I cannot find any supporting literature. I was hoping somebody here could direct me in the correct direction.

Comment: Can you please explain the symbols? Not everyone knows. Plus, whatever $d_{\theta}$ is, the first equation looks dimensionally inconsistent.

Comment: @New_new_newbie I accidently wrote $d_\theta$ twice, I've corrected it.

Comment: http://www.physicsinsights.org/dipole_field_1.html